# UIPopOver is disappearing unnecessarily

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I have implemented UIPopOver in my class to display certain options, in simulator it is working properly but in device it is disappearing even if I do not click on any other area.Can anyone know why popover is behaving weirdly in device?And how I can overcome this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the code you use to display your controller. A wild guess would be that your controller is not retained correctly and may be released or its parent controller is being released.

You should also check that you simulator is running the same ios version as your device.

Can't help more without more details.

Comment: Thanks CitronEvanescent for your reply.Actually I got the reason it was disappearing because on change of orientation I was dismissing popover and the code for dismissing popover I had written in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation instead of didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation so I moved my code to didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation and it is working perfectly.